# How do we find high traffic duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I noticed that this question just got 10,000 views:

- [How to install java and enable java plug in for firefox in Ubuntu 12.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137704/how-to-install-java-and-enable-java-plug-in-for-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04lts)

I've flagged it to either be merged or have the answer removed so that autoforwarding from search engine works, as outlined here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2317/what-can-we-do-about-high-traffic-duplicates

However, other than browsing through the popular question badge, is there a smarter way we can make sure incoming high traffic duplicates go to the right place?

Comment: how do you define duplicates?

Comment: Questions that are repeats of ones asked before.

Comment: but how are you defining repeat? I ask because sometimes there are small variations that impact one set up and may not affect another.

Comment: I just read both questions. These questions are already closed as duplicates, I just want to find them so that we can ensure the autoforwarding from search engines works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can possibly use the search parameters and see if things are going well:

- [views:5000 closed:1 "possible duplicate" answers:1](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=views%3A5000+closed%3A1+%22possible+duplicate%22+answers%3A1)

The data is pretty live and will look for questions that are closed as duplicates and have more than 5000 views. You can tweak the page view count and find the questions as you see is relevant.